# Projections for ADO Data services

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm, wcf-data-services, odata

I have existing database and ADO Data services on top of it. Right now we decided to create simple MVVM mobile client for our system, but we do not need all the data, just the subset. So we decided to use projections when we query the service.

So first question, what is the best approach to do it? Create addition service operations? and use them to query the data?

Also we have auto generated entities from ADO Data services, but as I understood we need additional entities types on the client side? Would it be good to use them for the Model layer on the client side?

How can we track/save changes in our projection types? Cause we want them to be sent back to the data service when the SaveChanges method is called?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you consider using client requested projections? That is $select...

/Products?$select=Name,Description

Comment: Yes, LINQ-queries with Select section. But how to deal with additional entities?

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand the question, could you maybe post a simple example?

Comment: for example, from c in scv.Persons select new { First = c.First }, I do not want anonymous types, I want to create strongly-typed object, so I should add new class for each projection and then use them for databiding. The question was how to save/track these classes? and is it good practise in general? Sorry if I misunderstood something.

Comment: You can always use a new class for each projection. If you have the DataServiceEntityAttribute on that class, you should be able to query/update these objects using the DataServiceContext class.